# XCode errors in CFString.h: "Use of undeclared identifier 'true'"

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-errors, core-foundation

I have been pulling my hairs out over errors that have suddenly appeared in my Mac OS (10.7) App. Build fails with multiple errors in `CFString.h:`

`Use of undeclared identifier 'true'`

`CGGeometry.h`:

```
Function cannot return function of type 'bool' (aka 'int (int)')
```

and many more...

Clearly my project settings are wrong, but I have played with the build settings, tried to make sure I link to all the frameworks I need, cleaned the build folder, restarted Xcode, reinstalled XCode, started a new project and pulled over all the files... Still getting these errors! Other projects compile OK.

I have no idea why this is happening, so not sure what other details are relevant, but I'll be happy to provide whatever info is necessary...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Managed to get it working now! Just in case anyone else is having a similar problem: the cause was renaming the folder containing the project. Undoing that resolved the issue, as did creating a fresh project, this time taking care not to rename the folder...

Comment: I haven't renamed any folder yet I still have this problem.